# const float array in WebGL shader

Tags: arrays, constants, three.js, webgl, shader

I'm using THREE.js with WebGL shader. I want to declare an array of float numbers in fragment shader. The GLSL constant float array is defined like:

```
#define KERNEL_LENGTH 9
const float kernel[KERNEL_LENGTH] = {
    1.0/16.0, 2.0/16.0, 1.0/16.0,
    2.0/16.0, 4.0/16.0, 2.0/16.0,
    1.0/16.0, 2.0/16.0, 1.0/16.0
};
```

I've also tried with:

```
#define KERNEL_LENGTH 9
const float kernel[KERNEL_LENGTH] = float[KERNEL_LENGTH](
    1.0/16.0, 2.0/16.0, 1.0/16.0,
    2.0/16.0, 4.0/16.0, 2.0/16.0,
    1.0/16.0, 2.0/16.0, 1.0/16.0
);
```

But with WebGL, neither of them works. Error information:

> ERROR: 0:44: 'kernel' : arrays may not be declared constant since they cannot be initialized 
>   ERROR: 0:44: '=' : syntax error

So how should I define an array of const float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a walk-around:

```
float kernel[KERNEL_LENGTH];
kernel[0] = kernel[4] = kernel[20] = kernel[24] = 1.0/273.0;
kernel[1] = kernel[3] = kernel[5] = kernel[9] = kernel[15] = kernel[19] 
    = kernel[21] = kernel[23] = 4.0/273.0;
kernel[2] = kernel[10] = kernel[14] = kernel[22] = 7.0/273.0;
kernel[6] = kernel[8] = kernel[16] = kernel[18] = 16.0/273.0;
kernel[7] = kernel[11] = kernel[13] = kernel[17] = 26.0/273.0;
kernel[12] = 41.0/273.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the values as uniforms, rather than trying to do what it tells you you cannot: initialize an array as constants.

Comment: I don't want to pass them into the shader, because the values are always constant.

Comment: a little secret: "constant" values are always passed as uniforms to the GPU

Comment: Are you sure that there're no const variables in WebGL?

Comment: What will be faster: use an array-type uniform or hardcode the logic into the shader as in Ovilia's answer?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the compiler would recognize both as equivalent.